# How to join multiple MethodCallExpressions into one Expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have a query and I need to apply n filters to it. However I have to use expressions. So far I have expression constructed for each filter, which works pretty good. Issue is I want to join these filters into one expression so I could use it as parameter for LINQ's .Where().

Filter code:

```
    //Filters could slightly differ in functionality 
    private Expression<Func<T, bool>> StringPropertyContains<T>(Filter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filter));
        }

        if (typeof(T).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(pi => pi.Name.Equals(filter.PropertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"Type {typeof(T)} does not contain property {filter.PropertyName}");
        }

        var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(filter.PropertyName);
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var member = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, propertyInfo);
        var constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value, typeof(filter.Type));
        var methodInfo = typeof(filter.Type).GetMethod(filter.Method, new Type[] { typeof(filter.Type) });
        var body = Expression.Call(member, methodInfo, constant);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
    }

    private Expression<Func<T, bool>> Filter<T>(T t)
    {
        //TODO join filters while each filter should have its different parameter
        //the parameter is currently constructed in the object and is accessible via property Filter[] ParsedFilter
    }
```

Filter class:

```
internal class Filter
{
    public string Type { get; }
    public string Method { get; }
    public string PropertyName { get; }
    public string Value { get; }
}
```

Desired usage:

```
IQueryable<T> q = query.Where(this.Filter)
```

To be honest I have pretty bad headache with this issue because I am pretty new to expressions. So thanks in regards for any help.

Comment: Are you asking how to combine multiple `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`? If the combinator is `&&` (AND), you can simply chain multiple `Where`. Or use some predicate builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass a class as argument to a Where clause however you can use Linq Expressions to acheive what you want:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = q => q.type == filter.Type && q.Value == filter.Value;

var x = query.Where(filter);
```